# MySQL apply --base64-output=decode-rows to MYSQL servers

Tags: mysql, binlog

I have decoded some of my binary logs using the following command.

```
mysqlbinlog mysql-bin-changelog.003495 --base64-output=DECODE-ROWS --verbose --verbose --verbose > sqlfile
```

This has the content like

```
BEGIN
/*!*/;
# at 962
#220901 12:46:49 server id 1093105432  end_log_pos 1053 CRC32 0xe0280fac        Table_map: `apps`.`flyway_schema_history` mapped to number 135
# at 1053
#220901 12:46:49 server id 1093105432  end_log_pos 1175 CRC32 0x4bba23d3        Write_rows: table id 135 flags: STMT_END_F
INSERT INTO `apps`.`flyway_schema_history`
SET
  @1=1 /* INT meta=0 nullable=0 is_null=0 */
# at 1175
#220901 12:46:49 server id 1093105432  end_log_pos 1206 CRC32 0x22a41532        Xid = 319345
COMMIT;/*!*/;
```

It had many lines but I removed unwanted statements, Now I have the clean file. But when I directly apply this into MySQL via `mysql -u<USER> -p db < file.sql` it gives an error.

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 8: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@1=1


COMMIT' at line 3
```

How do I apply this statement?

Comment: Does the manual talk about this use for the binlogs?

Comment: I don't think so, but check if someone cracked this already

Comment: I would guess that "apply" was intended to work only for things like "point-in-tim-recovery", and not intended for 'editing'.